# django tutorial manage.py sql polls produces no output

Tags: python, django

THIS IS NOW FIXED: the problem was.. code did exist in the models, it was saved correctly as I have shutdown and rebooted overnight and the code was saved correctly. However, when i commited to github, someone correctly noticed it was missing. The models file appeared to be empty. I cut, then re pasted the code back in, saved, and pushed it back up to the repo. When I ran manage.py sql polls again, the correct sql was generated. no idea what the problem was, it was saved to disk correctly. Thanks to anyone that took a look.

I am just going through the django tutorial, I am on ubuntu with django 1.4.1 installed, using python 2.7, and MySql as the db. I have created the database and run syncdb successfully to create the default tables.

Everything has worked so far, and all the correct directories appear to have been created. My models have no typos (after searching for an answer I have noticed that previous versions of the tutorial have contained typos and other errors). I have searched for a while now, and no answer that has been posted before seems to fix the problem I am having.

django is correctly installed, from the terminal I can successfully import django.

I have added 'polls' to the INSTALLED_APPS.

When I run python manage.py sql polls, it simply goes to the next line in the terminal with no output and no errors. if I run manage.py validate I get no errors.

I could be wrong, but I believe that when I ran python manage.py startapp polls, it should have added the path to this app to the PYTHONPATH, this does not seem to have happened.

However, when I temporarily add the path using sys.path.append(... it is there, but this does not fix the problem either. Help greatly appreciated been looking for a while..

thanks

as requested in comments, here is the tree structure of the project

```
└── mysite
    ├── manage.py
    ├── mysite
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __init__.pyc
    │   ├── settings.py
    │   ├── settings.pyc
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   ├── urls.pyc
    │   ├── wsgi.py
    │   └── wsgi.pyc
    └── polls
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── __init__.pyc
        ├── models.py
        ├── models.pyc
        ├── tests.py
        └── views.py
```

Comment: You don't need to add an app to PYTHONPATH. The folder containing the app folder should be on python path. This and adding the name of the app to INSTALLED_APPS in a project's settings.py is all you need to do to make the app visible to a given project.

Comment: Can you paste your directory structure starting from project root. Use `tree` linux command if needed.

Comment: thanks for the info IamChuck. Pratik, I have added dir structure to question..

Comment: can you show output of syncdb command. Since i tried same steps what you told. For me it works fine.

Comment: could there be a typo in `settings.py` - like, a missing comma?

Comment: I have added a link to the public repo in the question. The output of syncdb is: Creating tables ...
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s) - This makes sense, as the script is not being generated, when syncdb is run, it does not perform any operations.. so it seems the models are not being picked up. thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Your models.py for the polls app seems to have no models so there is no sql to generate
https://github.com/felbus/pythonbits/blob/master/django/mysite/polls/models.py

Comment: that was a mistake with the commit.. there is code in models.. i have updated the repo, the problem still exists.. thanks for looking - update, now fixed, see top of question

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. But, the code was still there (unlike this case where the code was missed during commit)

To fix the issue, I added the projectname.polls to the INSTALLED_APPS - This fixed the issue and the python manage.py sql polls  gave the expected output.

Just to clarify, add projectname.polls (whatever your project name is!) in INSTALLED_APPS and use just polls in manage.py args. (Fixed my issue, may fix yours!)

I use Python 2.7 (ActivePython), PostGres 9.3 and Django 1.5.5